# Converting String to Ordinal Value

Tags: python, ordinals

I'm looking to compute the
sum of the ordinal values of all the characters of the full name string, and will output this
sum.

here is what I have so far.

```
a = input('Enter your first name: ')
b = input('Enter your last name: ')
c = print("your full name is:", a, b)
print(ord(a))
```

so for example if you put Mary for the first name and Joe for the last name the full name would be Mary Joe and the ordinal value would be 727.

Comment: `print(sum(ord(i) for i in a+b))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only concatenate `a` and `b` you will get `695`:

```
print(sum(ord(i) for i in a+b))
# 695
```

But, it seems you also need a space between the first and last name:

```
print(sum(ord(i) for i in '{0} {1}'.format(a, b)))
# 727
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a for loop like so `num=sum([ord(i) for i in c],0)` assuming c is "Mary Joe" or the string you want. Also, you should use `raw_input` if you want the user to give you a string, and for printing use `print "your full name is: " + c`